# Another four chickens

Tags: word-usage

As I understand another = an + other, which has turned into a single word through the history of English. As a consequence, it refers to a single object (another car = one car, another bite = one bite). But I wasn't sure about the expression "Another four chickens". The expression sounds good to my ears, but bad to my (little) grammar knowledge.

My two questions are:

> 1. Is it correct?
> 2. If so, when can *another* be used for plural?

Comment: Here's my initial thought. You can't say "Another dog*s*" but you can say "Another group of dog*s*" or "Another four dog*s*." Here, "four dogs" acts like a *collective noun*, much like "group" and "group of dogs", which has *both* singular *and* plural properties. To see that "Another four dogs" is at least quasi-singular, just consider the acceptability of "Another four dogs *is* too many" (contrast this with the unacceptability of "Another four dogs *are* too many").

Comment: Right. So, to answer the question, yes, it's correct, and _another_ can't be used for plural. It's ok in this case because _four dogs_ is a singular numbered group. I.e, the _four_ is important; you can't use just any word -- *_another red dogs_  or *_another dying dogs_ are impossible.

Comment: But "Another four dogs" is also semi-plural, as evinced by the acceptability of "Another four dogs *run* up" versus * "Another four dogs *runs* up."

Comment: Compare 'an extra three sessions' / 'a further three weeks' for the article usage (though here, the 'one more' etymology doesn't intrude).

Comment: @JohnLawler Not impossible. "I've heard John won't be playing tonight. Isn't he playing for the Red Dogs anymore?" - "He is, but what we are going to see tonight is **another Red Dogs.** From Seattle.

Comment: Proper names are, as usual, reified and don't work like normal compounds. *_New English boiled dinner_, *_Toronto Maple Leaves_.

Comment: @Centaurus I can't see anything wrong with your _...what we are going to see tonight is another Red Dogs_. "Another" is, after all, an alternative-additive determinative, and you are using it in its 'alternative' sense where the meaning is "a different Red Dogs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the dicitonary entry here:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/another

Consider the first definition

> Used to refer to an additional person or thing 
>   of the same type as one already mentioned or known about; 
>   one more; a further

I would say that **another** should not be used in the plural, unless we are talking about a set or a group similar to the one already described or known about.

**We bought another four chickens.**

...implies that we already had a set of four chickens, and we bought another set of four. This is similar to

**Put on another pair.**

If I were to say,

**Have another three drinks.**

...this would imply and call attention to the proposition that the person being addressed has already had (a set of) three drinks.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the substance of your answer. But the logic of it doesn't hold up. There's no reason to say that quantitatively matching sets are implied in any way. Even if you want to rigidly apply a "set" rule, each set is itself singular composite of plurals. A practical demonstration of this is using the synonym in your linked definition. "We have 1 chicken at home and a further 4 chickens will be delivered tomorrow". Either usage is semantically and syntactically equal.